# MySQL - Simple search for ID and return name

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

G'day,

I'm not familiar with MySQL and this will probably be an easy question!

I am trying to mod a Joomla plugin and am working with this code that works well for a similar function:

```
$q="SELECT `".$naming."` AS naming FROM `#__users` WHERE `id`='".$jomsocial_event->creator."' ";
$db->setQuery($q);
$eventcreatorname = $db->loadResult();
$eventcreator = '<a href=\"'.CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid='.$jomsocial_event->creator).'\">'.addslashes($eventcreatorname).'</a>';
```

What I need to do is lookup the field `id` in the table `community_groups` and return the matching field `name`. What I have is (note that `$jomsocial_event->contentid` contains the group ID):

```
$q="SELECT `".$naming."` AS naming FROM `#__community_groups` WHERE `id`='".$jomsocial_event->contentid."' ";
$db->setQuery($q);
$eventgroupname = $db->loadResult();
$eventgroup = '<a href=\"'.CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid='.$jomsocial_event->contentid).'\">'.addslashes($eventcreatorname).'</a>';
```

It returns nothing as the query is wrong; what should it be for my usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd work backwards from the database.

i.e. turn on SQL logging and look at what's actually arriving in the database. Tweak as necessary by playing with the resulting SQL until you get what you want (and expect) and then implement that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your generated query in the debugging from Joomla.
Run it against mysql directly and see where it goes wrong.

Also, I'd use the JDatabaseQuery API because you are much less likely to get errors with quoting etc. It looks to me like you are treating id as a string not an integer.